# Visual Composer custom markup for custom shortcode (vc_map)

Tags: wordpress

Trying to get **custom_markup** to work with the Visual Composer builder for WordPress.

Found [Visual Composer change custom shortcode template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073053/visual-composer-change-custom-shortcode-template) and also [Visual Composer custom shortcode template - custom_markup display user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745605/visual-composer-custom-shortcode-template-custom-markup-display-user-input) but none of them has an answer.

Here's some documentation for the **vc_map** function https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=524332

Here's my shortcode that I'm using, everything works perfectly, it just looks horrible in the backend ui

```
vc_map( array(
      "name" => "example",
      "base" => "adwise_vc_example",
      "class" => "",
      "category" => "Plugin name",
      "icon" => "awm_vc_icon",
      "custom_markup" => load_template( ADWISE_VC_DIR . '/vc_templates/adwise_example.php', false),
      "params" => array();
```

Which currently looks like --> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11204765/SS/mac/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-02%20at%2012.52.56.png

In the example below I've tried to set **custom_markup** to **test**

which results in https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11204765/SS/mac/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-02%20at%2012.45.55.png

```
vc_map( array(
      "name" => "example",
      "base" => "adwise_vc_example",
      "class" => "",
      "category" => "Plugin name",
      "icon" => "awm_vc_icon",
      "custom_markup" => "test",
      "params" => array();
```

My primary/main problem is that I don't know how to get the values of each attribute for each shortcode to display in the template file.

I've looked almost everywhere for a solution, including browsing through other Visual Composer plugins to see how they've accomplished this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm also trying to solve this issue. Unfortunately, looks like all your original linked images here are 404.

Comment: @TimHallman yeah sorry about that, shortly after Dropbox changed their public folder rules i stopped using Dropbox altogether, i don't belive i have a copy of those images.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, seems to require a decent bit of JavaScript that works with WPBakery Page Builders Backbone script and i never got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish exactly ? From the visual composer core code this is the custom markup for the tabs

```
'custom_markup' => '
<div class="wpb_tabs_holder wpb_holder vc_container_for_children">
<ul class="tabs_controls">
</ul>
%content%
</div>',
```

So maybe something like **%customattr%** will get your desired result?

Comment: Not sure if you've checked the screenshots, one example of what I'm trying to do; if you look at this screenshot --> [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11204765/SS/mac/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-02%20at%2012.52.56.png) you can see the number "6" on every row right? That's the image ID, but what i want is to display the image it self instead of just the ID, I've seen several plugins doing this, but haven't been able to find their method in their code.

I've already tried to use the _%custom%_ in my template and directly in the PHP. - @digitalzoomstudio

Comment: @Dym: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

just add an array with the shortcode attributes in 'params'

```
'params' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'textfield',
                'holder' => 'div',
                'class' => '',
                'heading' => __( 'Title' ),
                'param_name' => 'title',
                'value' => __( 'Titre' ),
                'description' => __( 'Title' ),
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'holder' => 'div',
                'class' => '',
                'heading' => __( 'Description' ),
                'param_name' => 'desc',
                'value' => __( 'description' ),
                'description' => __( 'Description' ),
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'attach_image',
                'holder' => 'img',
                'class' => '',
                'heading' => __( 'Image' ),
                'param_name' => 'img_url',
                'value' => __( '' ),
                'description' => __( 'Image' ),
            ),

        )
```

and if you want hide a section in the backend just remove the 'holder' line

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, didn't get a response for a long time so stopped checking in >.< anyways, there are sections that i want to hide, but also sections that i'd want to customize. - For example, using the Visual Composer image picker will store the selected images in a string, all ID's separated by commas for example -- `[gallery_shortcode image_ids="10,25,30,35,45,46"]` there are however certain shortcodes from other Visual Composer plugins that actually show the selected images in the backend and not just all the ID's. @Hassan

Comment: Here's an example how it looks in other plugins --> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11204765/DNT/stackoverflow/vc-ext-example-02.jpg - However, when i do the same it only displays the image ID's - Same thing happens to URL's, example --> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11204765/DNT/stackoverflow/vc-ext-example-03.jpg @Hassan